# Do not wrap certain environments

Tags: filetype-tex, wrapping

I am using `neovim`.

When editing a `.tex` file I don't want to wrap the lines within certain environments like `equation` or `align` and some others.

```
\begin{equation}
    % very long line I don't want to wrap because \left( \frac{}{} \right) is very long and wrapping makes it harder to read
\end{equation}
And I want these lines to be wrapped because its text with some possible
inline maths. I am ok with inline math being wrapped for example $ax^2+b
x+c=0$  doesn't bother me.
```

But I wan't rest of the documents to be wrapped as usual. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Except for writing your own format expression (see e.g. [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/format.vim)), I don't know any ways to do this. But, IMHO, it is very possible to write wrap long equations for readability. I actually think the opposite of you, that equations should be wrapped, but normal text should not be wrapped (i.e. one sentence or paragraph per line).